# android Apache httpclient upload file,. got some weird TCP reassembly error

Tags: java, android, apache, tcp

I am using Apache httpclient and multipart request to upload an image file to server.
I was able to upload file successfully through other clients such as iphone and fiddler to call same api call on server side. Not that lucky with Android...

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(appController.getInstance().getURL().concat("/Api/ApiSales/UploadImages"));
        post.addHeader("Authorization", appController.getInstance().getAuthTokenString());
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
File fileDir = new File( Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), Global.PHOTO_DIR);
        for (File file : fileDir.listFiles()){
            if (file.getName().equals("campusMarketLogo.png")){
                Log.i("", "found campus logo file!");
                FileInputStream fin = null;
                try {
                    fin = new FileInputStream(file);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.e("", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
byte[] fileContent = new byte[(int)file.length()];
                try {
                    fin.read(fileContent);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(fileContent,"image/png",file.getName());
                entity.addPart("File", bab);
            }
        }
        post.setEntity(entity);
        try {
            client.execute(post, new uploadResponseHandler());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("something is wrong", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
```

When I read my log from Wireshark, I saw some TCP error:

> [TCP Retransmission] 62941→80 [ACK] Seq=676 Ack=1 Win=14656 Len=1448 TSval=161633 TSecr=516688742[Reassembly error, protocol TCP: New fragment overlaps old data (retransmission?)]

Why would there be any TCP error like this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfectly acceptable behavior of TCP.  A lost return `ACK` will cause a retransmission of data that was actually received, possibly larger than the original and including later data as well.  The receiver will silently discard additional copies of data it has already received.